# System app Uninstallation without rooting

Tags: root-access, uninstallation, system-apps

How to Uninstall system apps without rooting? I have tried many applications but all of them require root permissions. Please help.

Comment: You can't. They are system apps for a reason.

Answer (score -2):

You can't uninstall them without root. You can disable them, though. 

If space is your concern, get an SD Card. If memory is your concern, Disable them.

or You could Root your device.